# Jquery carousel where prevoius and next button inside the each carousel slide

Tags: jquery, carousel

An jquery carousel where prev button and next button inside the carousel.

Normally carousel will have prev button on left side and next button right side

Is there any jquery carousel where prev and next buttons inside the carousel content ?

I need one slide at a time, every slides needs its  previous and next button inside the content of that slide

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use CSS to position the `prev` and `next` buttons to be inside the slide?

Answer (score 0):

Nivo slider.  Check out the demo.. http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/

You want to set "directionNav : true" per http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/

Answer (score 0):

With jquery cycle you can easily do this as well and there are two ways.

Plugin Download: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

**Demo 1:**

Add a prev and next button to each slide.  The next and previous buttons will animate with the slides because they are inside the slide.  The only reason you'd want to do this is if you wanted to animate those buttons with the slides.  Normally this isn't the case (see example 2)

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/anwvL/1/

The html would be something like this:

```
<div id="slideshow">

<div>
    <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a><a href="#" class="next">next</a>
    <img src="http://weblogs.marylandweather.com/4526619322_1912218db8.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a><a href="#" class="next">next</a>
    <img src="http://www.silverstar-academy.com/Blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/03-14-12N00184967.jpg" /></div>
<div>
      <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a><a href="#" class="next">next</a>
        <img src="http://cdn.the2012scenario.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/sunspot-500x500.jpg" /></div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    prev: $('.prev'),
    next: $('.next')
});​
```

**Demo 2**

We position the next/prev buttons on top of the slides but not inside the slides.  You will notice the prev/next buttons don't animate with the slides but are ontop of them.  This is typically what you see on most slideshows (as text or arrows)

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/hXxtJ/1/

```
<div id="sliders">
    <div class="controller">
       <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a><a href="#" class="next">next</a>
    </div>
    <div id="slideshow">

        <div>
            <img src="http://weblogs.marylandweather.com/4526619322_1912218db8.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://www.silverstar-academy.com/Blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/03-14-12N00184967.jpg" />
        </div>
         <div>
            <img src="http://cdn.the2012scenario.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/sunspot-500x500.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
​
```

JS:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    prev: $('.prev'),
    next: $('.next')
});​
```